# Phalcon aggerate sort with locale

Tags: php, mongodb, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I would like to make the ordering to be based on Hungarian sort order - for example: "aábc..z" instead of "abc..zá". So I would need to set the locale /collation to Hungarian.

My pipeline:

```
    [0] => array[1]
    (
        [$match] => array[1]
        (
            [$and] => array[2]
            (
                [0] => array[1]
                (
                    [aktiv] => true (boolean)
                )
                [1] => array[1]
                (
                    [aktivGondozott] => true (boolean)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => array[1]
    (
        [$project] => array[2]
        (
            [_id] => 1 (int) 
            [alapadatok] => array[1]
            (
                [$arrayElemAt] => array[2]
                (
                    [0] => '$alapadatok' (string) 
                    [1] => 0 (int) 
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [2] => array[1]
    (
        [$project] => array[3]
        (
            [_id] => 1 (int) 
            [teljesNev] => '$alapadatok.szuletesiTeljesNev' (string) 
            [szuletesiDatum] => '$alapadatok.szuletesiIdo' (string) 
        )
    )
    [3] => array[1]
    (
        [$sort] => array[1]
        (
            [teljesNev] => 1 (int) 
        )
    )
    [4] => array[1]
    (
        [$skip] => 380 (int) 
    )
    [5] => array[1]
    (
        [$limit] => 20 (int) 
    )
```

How to set locale to 'hu' at $sort in collection::aggregate() ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the locale in the collation document and pass it as aggregation options.

```
$m = new MongoClient;
$c = $m->selectDB("db")->selectCollection("col");
$pipeline = some pipeline
$options = array("collation" => array("locale" => "hu"));
$c->aggregate($pipeline, $options);
```